# Looping to read in large data files

Tags: matlab, for-loop, text-files

I know,there are already lot of questions been asked on this topic.Somehow I'm missing something which is giving me wrong results. So could someone please tell me where I'm going wrong.

I've a batch of large `.txt`files (500 MB - 900MB) in the same directory with sequence numbering like this.

```
EXPORT.001.txt,EXPORT.002.txt,EXPORT.003.txt,...... EXPORT.032.txt
```

I wanted to read each file and store the variables sequentially.

My code is

```
 files = dir('*.txt');
    for file = files'
 [time.file.name,Y_bt.file.name,Y_bc.file.name,X_bt.file.name,X_bc.file.name,X_C.file.name,Y_C.file.name,N_ot_an.file.name,N_ot_dig.file.name,n.file.name,n2.file.name] = import_file(file.name,startRow);
end
```

import_file is another function I created to readin each file.

```
function [Time,Y_bt,Y_bc,X_bt,X_bc,X_C,Y_C,N_ot_an,N_ot_dig,n,n2] = import_file(filename,startRow)

delimiter = {'\t',' '};
formatSpec = '%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f';
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
dataArray = textscan(fileID,formatSPec,'Delimiter','MultipleDelimsAsOne',true'EmptyValue',NaN,'HeaderLines',startRow-1,'ReturnOnError',false);

EXPORT = [dataArray{1:end}];
%Defining Individual channels

Time = EXPORT(:,2);
.
.
.
.
n2 = EXPORT(:,21);
fclose(fileID);

clear file ID;
```

When I run the program, I get only the data from last text file `EXPORT.032.txt` and the rest of the files are not read.

All I wanted to do with my program is create a structure array for all my variables from all the .txt files. For example `Time.file.name` should create a Structure with name `Time` and contain all the variables of Time from all data sets.  I wanted to use these data structures to call different variables to a same script of my program.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I can make a suggestion, having that many output variables in your function call is poor programming practice.  Consider returning a single structure that contains each of those output variables as fields.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to follow suggestions and modified my function `import_file` which would now just give one output as a `struct` array with all the channel variables in it. Now the problem I'm encountering is I get a struct array with mostly empty values. Is it something to do with preallocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting all your variables each loop iteration.

```
for ii = 1:10
    A = ii;
end
```

will result in `A` being a scalar with value 10.

```
for ii = 1:10
    A(ii) = ii;
end
```

will result in `A` being an array ranging from 1 to 10.

Use the loop variable `file` to append on each structure where you want it. You seem to have multiple nested structures, I'm not sure in which one you want to store it, but `time(file.name)` seems to be what you're looking for.

A good way to clean up your code would be to store everything in a *single* structure in your function, so you can call single structures as output in your script, making it more readable and less prone to errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question based upon your suggestion and  I've few more questions.

Comment: @PBCR If this answer solved your previous question then instead of changing it you should ask a new question.

Comment: @IKavanagh. I'm sorry for the confusion. It didn't really solve the question.  I still have more bugs and trying to clarify them. Or if you think I need to start another question I can do that but that would lead to just creating modified clone version of this question.

Comment: @PBCR A cursory glance to me suggests this solves your original problem (particularly the title of the question) providing you implement it correctly. Your new question (the edit) appears sufficiently different to be ok for a new question to me. I would roll it back and ask a new question.

Comment: @IKavanagh Alright, I took it off the grid :) I posted another question. May be you wanna look at this.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542457/preallocation-for-looping-large-data-files-in-matlab) Thanks

Comment: @PBCR Upon reading your new question it seems that you haven't actually taken the advice in this answer, specifically the `A(ii)` part.

Comment: @IKavanagh.I'm a newbie to MATLAB. Could you please elaborate where I'm going wrong. I want to learn things. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @PBCR Could you please delete the subsequent question as it is a duplicate of this? What's happening is you are overwriting your variables. You need to change your `for` loop to loop over the number of files. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33541937/1552737) is probably of more help to you. You may also want to ask for help in the [Matlab and Octave Chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave).

Comment: @IKavanagh, If I use the approach you referred. I'm getting a error from `fopen` which says `first input must be a filename of type char , or a file identifier of type double`