# Convert mutiple 2-dimensional .mat files into single 3-dimensional .mat in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have 79 .mat files each contain a 264*264 array named "CM". I want to combine them all into a single 264*264*79 matrix but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
files=dir('*.mat') %// load all filenames from the directory ending on .mat
for ii = numel(files):-1:1 %// let the loop run backwards
    load(files(ii).name);
    A(:,:,ii) = CM; %// assumed they are actually all equivalently called CM
end
```

The `dir` command get a list of all files in the `pwd` (present working directory). The the `for` loop runs backwards, so as to initialise the storage variable `A` to its maximum size, improving efficiency. Within the loop, load a file and then store it in `A`. Finally `A` will be a `[264 264 79]` array.

Comment: Thanks, but it give me an error:
Warning: Number of elements exceeds maximum flint 2^53-1.
The result may be inaccurate. 
Warning: FOR loop index is too large. Truncating to 281474976710655. 
Field reference for multiple structure elements that is followed by
more reference blocks is an error.

Comment: Apparently you CM is not as simple as a simple array. Please load a single one into your workspace and call `whos(CM)`, so we can see what's inside there, since it is not a simple array.

Comment: It might be, that this code hit some mat files which you did not intend to load. Could you check that `files` only contains the intended mat files?

Comment: @Daniel how is it even possible to store multiple variables called `CM`? Is it that if you call it e.g. `CM1.mat`, when loaded it still shows `CM` as variable name? Because if he has some form of sequential file naming, it's an easy fix. If he has indeed more mat files than those 79, it'd be more than 2^53-1 files. That's quite a lot of files.

Comment: There is a bug in the code, it should be `numel(files)`

Comment: Adriaan results of 'code' whos('CM') 'code': CM, 264x264, 557568, double 
@Daniel as Adriaan said all have CM as only variable in them and I can not load them cause they overlap with eachother

Comment: The error is caused by `load(files.name(ii));`, it should be `load(files(ii).name);`

Comment: @Daniel after your correction error is reduced to only this: 
Field reference for multiple structure elements that is followed by more reference blocks is an error.

Comment: @Daniel thanks. I'm still confused with this new `dir` functionality.. I'll trump up some test data to try them out for myself...

Comment: Thanks all. After final correction it's now working.